# When $f$ is integrable, for what $g$ does $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) du = \int_a^b f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) dx$ hold?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I am reading "Calculus 4th Edition" by Michael Spivak.

There are the following problems and theorem in this book.

> On p. 274 Problem 14.
> If $f$ is integrable, then
> $$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_{a+c}^{b+c} f(x-c) dx.$$

> On p. 275 Problem 16.
> If $f$ is integrable, then
> $$\int_{ca}^{cb} f(t) dt = c \int_a^b f(ct) dt.$$

> On p. 369 Theorem 2.
> If $f$ and $g'$ are continuous, then $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) du = \int_a^b f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) dx.$$

By Problems 14 and 16, if $f$ is integrable, then
$$\int_{ca+d}^{cb+d} f(u) du = \int_{ca}^{cb} f(u+d) du = c \int_a^b f(cx+d) dx.$$
Of course, if $f$ is continuous, the above equation holds by Theorem 2.

When $f$ is integrable, for what $g$ does $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) du = \int_a^b f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) dx$$ hold?

Comment: A more general theorem is by Kestelman: if $g$ is Riemann integrable on  $[a, b] $, $f$ is Riemann integrable on an interval containing $G([a, b]) $ and $G(x) =\int_a^x g(t) \, dt$ then $\int_{G(a)} ^{G(b)} f(x) \,dx=\int_{a} ^{b} f(G(t)) g(t) \, dt$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much for your answer again.

Comment: Also it is interesting to note that $f(G(t)) $ may not be Riemann integrable, but the product $f(G(t)) g(t) $ is Riemann integrable. The proof by Kestelman is a bit complicated.